# Having trouble pulling form values from POST in Express/node/jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post

I want to get values from a form and pass them to a SQL query. This is for a simple CRUD API I'm trying to build, and I know there is a lot wrong with this code. Right now, I'm focused on why the post route isn't logging the request body to the console from the post request in the script tag in the head. Page comes up, but nothing happens when I click submit.

```
const pg = require('pg');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const  $ = require('jquery');

const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 
'postgres://localhost:5432/hiking';

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {


res.end(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var firstName
            ,lastName
            ,mountainName;
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                firstName=$("#firstName").val();
                lastName=$("#lastName").val();
                mountainName=$("#mountainName").val();
                $.post("http://localhost:3000/inputs", {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, mountainName: mountainName}, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                })


            });
        }));


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            First ame: <input type="text"   id="firstName" /><br />
            Last Name: <input type="text"   id="lastName"  /><br />
            Mountain Peak Name: <input type="text"  id="mountainName"  /><br />
            <input type="file"  id="file"         /><br />
            <button>Save</button><br /><br /><br />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </body>


    </html>
`);
});

var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.post('/inputs', function(req,res){
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var mountainName = req.body.mountainName;
    console.log(req.body);
});



const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
const query = client.query('SELECT * from public.hike LIMIT 1', (err, res) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err.stack)
    } else
        console.log(res.rows)
}) ;

console.log("Ready.");

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your html is dynamically added, you need to take reference to static element while doing certain event with that element. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

When an HTML document is loaded into a web browser, it becomes a document object. The document object is the root node of the HTML document. So, you need to use document object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstName, lastName, mountainName;
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
        firstName = $(document).find("#firstName").val();
        lastName = $(document).find("#lastName").val();
        mountainName = $(document).find("#mountainName").val();
        $.post("http://localhost:3000/inputs", {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            mountainName: mountainName
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I still don't see any console output though.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the jQuery import in my HTML template. Adding this line into the head tag fixed it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```